# how can I create a deb package from click qml application?

Tags: application-submission

I would like to publish my qml click application on ubuntu software center for install it on PC.
I tried to send the click package but prompted a deb package.
How do I get a dab package of a click application?
It 's really necessary this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes it is absolutely necessary** to create a .deb package to get into the Debian archives.  And after you've entered it there, you'll have to sign the Ubuntu code of conduct and then it'll go to the Ubuntu repositories.  (That one's easy: e-mail only)

For more info on the first step: https://wiki.debian.org/HowToPackageForDebian

**However,** if I'm not mistaken, you also have to *show up in person* to one of the Debian events with ID and have your public key signed by at least 2 other Debian developers.  That's how they keep out the virus boys...

Comment: I had read that you could use click packages olso for desktop app from version 14.10 of ubuntu.

Comment: I don't know.  I only know 1 Debian developer...  And as you're a reputation 6 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)